# How to wait until another pod starts running using init containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

```
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
```

I am using nslookup to wait until another service comes up. However, that does not solve my problem. As service will comes up but the corresponding app - pod maybe not ready. In this case, service dependency wont be handle.

How to ensure that one app1 is running before start app2?

Comment: What do you mean by `app1` running? In K8s, once all containers(not the initcontainers) have started, that means your Pod is running. It does not mean that your application in the container is ready to operate yet or is in initializing phase whatever it is. So, actually what do you mean by `running` app1 from your perspective. And make more clear your question to the developer.

Comment: This question is regarding pod dependency. Let's say app1(pod1) should wait until app2(pod2) to start. How we can achieve this using init-container.

Comment: If your Pod2 exposes its app2 at some port(s) and checking the availability of the service DNS/endpoint along with the port for app2 is enough for the waiting condition of app1, then you should specify that in your question too. In that way, you may get faster response. BTW, in this case, sometimes I use the `peer-finder` program from official Kubernetes https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/tree/master/peer-finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with docker-compose in the past. There are two approaches I used to resolve them. Both of them assume that services will expose a port to listen to.

1. **Simple and easy**: wait for the specific port of the application to be up an listening with a timeout command. This is very similar to what you are already doing. So your `command` will be something like:

   ```yaml
   initContainers:
   - name: init-myservice
       image: busybox:1.28
       command: ['sh', '-c', "until timeout 2 bash -c \"</dev/tcp/myservice/${MY_SERVICE_TCP_PORT}\"; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
   ```
2. **Versatile but with extra dependency**: Use the wonderful [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) tool. A lightweight binary that will control the dependencies between containers. It also does many other things, like control the log from a log file, or perform configuration templating. The only downside is that you are introducing a new dependency in your container, but in my opinion is totally worth it. In this case you can perform tcp and http checks of liveness for the services, and even introduces headers in the http ones (very useful for authenticated endpoints).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the first approach.However,init-container keep in waiting state:

`timeout: can't execute '2': No such file or directory
waiting for myservice`

Are we missing here anything- timeout command or argument?

Comment: It seems that it isn't recognized the timeout command correctly. I actually don't know what could be wrong. You can try to launch the command as a single string instead of an array.

Comment: nvm. I am able to do using nc command.
nc -w $TIMEOUT_SECONDS -v $HOST $PORT </dev/null; echo $?

Comment: Great @RajenPatel !! Feel free to edit my response to include your working solution.